# Localization of dynamic rendered user control

Tags: c#, localization, user-controls, asmx

Im using the following code to load a page dynamically from JavaScript

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetSimpleControl(string usercontrolName)
{
    Page page = new Page();
    UserControl ctl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl(usercontrolName);

    page.Controls.Add(ctl);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

My problem is, that it's not localized, but always uses the default language. In the user control I'm loading, I try to call `InitializeCulture` and set the culture:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by setting the UICulture and Culture of the page. The `GetSimpleControl` now looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetSimpleControl(string usercontrolName)
{
    Page page = new Page();
    page.Culture = "en";
    page.UICulture = "en";
    UserControl ctl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl(usercontrolName);

    page.Controls.Add(ctl);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
    return writer.ToString();
```

}